# Inspecting variables of a running Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, debugging, kernel-module

I have a crashed Linux system, where a special kernel module is loaded that does not respond to its assigned interrupt anymore. Is it possible to access the Internals of that specific module to see what has happened? Can it be done in a running system or do I need to modify the kernel, the module? Any hints are welcome.

Comment: You have a kernel oops or panic, I suppose? If so, the system log might contain the backtrace of the crashed code as well as other useful info. The rest depend on what exactly you are trying to do. [KGDB](https://kgdb.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) is worth looking at, as well as [this](http://elinux.org/Debugging_The_Linux_Kernel_Using_Gdb).

Comment: If you can execute commands on the system after the crash, you can also try to use gdb on the kernel memory as if it was the core dump file: `gdb -c /proc/kcore` (as root). Seems not to work on some systems but quite useful on the others.

Comment: No, there is nothing like an oops or a dumped core. The driver simply stops working. Investigating the stuff further showed that the interrupt behavior seems to have changed from level-triggered to edge-triggered. Changing the ISR accordingly seems to have fixed it but extensive testing is still required and running. If it is really fixed, this question becomes academic ;) I believe KGDB is what I was looking for, so I will give it a try as soon as I find some time to do so.